# (Spring)On the main page, users see all messages from the database, but it is necessary that they see only personal messages from user to user

Tags: java, spring, security

`For a long time I can not understand what the problem is, maybe I already want to sleep. In general, messages on the main page of the site show all messages from all users, that is, you can go to someone else's personal correspondence, how to fix it/

Looked for a problem in the backend and frontend, I think that the error is related to the definition of the user's role or request for a message`

`Chat conroller-`

```
package com.ghostchat.ghostchat.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import com.ghostchat.ghostchat.models.User;
import com.ghostchat.ghostchat.models.Message; // Импорт модели Message
import com.ghostchat.ghostchat.repos.UserRepo;
import com.ghostchat.ghostchat.repos.MessageRepo; // Импорт репозитория MessageRepo
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

@Controller
public class ChatController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepo messageRepo;

    @GetMapping("/chat")
    public String chat(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Messenger");
        List<User> allUsers = userRepo.findAll();
        String senderUsername = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();

        User currentUser = userRepo.findByUsername(senderUsername); // Получение текущего пользователя

        // Получение входящих сообщений для текущего пользователя
        List<Message> incomingMessages = messageRepo.findByRecipient(currentUser);

        model.addAttribute("allUsers", allUsers);
        model.addAttribute("senderUsername", senderUsername);
        model.addAttribute("incomingMessages", incomingMessages); // Передача входящих сообщений в шаблон
        return "chat";
    }


    @PostMapping("/send")
    public String sendMessage(@RequestParam String senderUsername,
                              @RequestParam String recipientUsername,
                              @RequestParam String messageText) {
        User sender = userRepo.findByUsername(senderUsername);
        User recipient = userRepo.findByUsername(recipientUsername);

        Message message = new Message();
        message.setSender(sender);
        message.setRecipient(recipient);
        message.setMessageText(messageText);
        message.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());

        messageRepo.save(message);

        return "redirect:/chat";
    }
    @GetMapping("/update-messages")
    public String updateMessages(@RequestParam String username, Model model) {
        User currentUser = userRepo.findByUsername(username);

        List<Message> incomingMessages = messageRepo.findByRecipient(currentUser);
        incomingMessages.sort(Comparator.comparing(Message::getTimestamp).reversed());

        model.addAttribute("incomingMessages", incomingMessages);

        return "message-list"; // Убедитесь, что это соответствует имени вашего шаблона Thymeleaf
    }

}
```

`---------Repo`

```
package com.ghostchat.ghostchat.repos;

import com.ghostchat.ghostchat.models.Message;
import com.ghostchat.ghostchat.models.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface MessageRepo extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {
    List<Message> findByRecipient(User recipient);
}
```

`----------Html-------------`

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<html lang="en" class="h-100" data-bs-theme="auto">
<head><script src="/docs/5.3/assets/js/color-modes.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.115.4">
    <title>Ghostchat.welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/cover/">



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@docsearch/css@3">

    <link href="/docs/5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/docs/5.3/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="180x180">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.3/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.3/assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/docs/5.3/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/docs/5.3/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#712cf9">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.3/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#712cf9">


    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }

      .b-example-divider {
        width: 100%;
        height: 3rem;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        border-width: 1px 0;
        box-shadow: inset 0 .5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 .125em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
      }

      .b-example-vr {
        flex-shrink: 0;
        width: 1.5rem;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      .bi {
        vertical-align: -.125em;
        fill: currentColor;
      }

      .nav-scroller {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        height: 2.75rem;
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }

      .nav-scroller .nav {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
        margin-top: -1px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      }

      .btn-bd-primary {
        --bd-violet-bg: #712cf9;
        --bd-violet-rgb: 112.520718, 44.062154, 249.437846;

        --bs-btn-font-weight: 600;
        --bs-btn-color: var(--bs-white);
        --bs-btn-bg: var(--bd-violet-bg);
        --bs-btn-border-color: var(--bd-violet-bg);
        --bs-btn-hover-color: var(--bs-white);
        --bs-btn-hover-bg: #6528e0;
        --bs-btn-hover-border-color: #6528e0;
        --bs-btn-focus-shadow-rgb: var(--bd-violet-rgb);
        --bs-btn-active-color: var(--bs-btn-hover-color);
        --bs-btn-active-bg: #5a23c8;
        --bs-btn-active-border-color: #5a23c8;
      }
      .bd-mode-toggle {
        z-index: 1500;
      }
      .message-list-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    background-color: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    /* Add the following properties to set a fixed height and enable scrolling */
    height: 300px; /* Set a fixed height */
    overflow-y: auto; /* Enable vertical scrolling */
}

.message-list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    /* Remove any margin to prevent unwanted spacing */
    margin: 0;
}
.chatbox-list-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    background-color: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    width: auto; /* Автоматически подстраиваться по ширине текста */
}


/* Стили для индивидуальных чатбоксов */
.chatbox {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex; /* Добавляем flex display */
    align-items: center; /* Выравниваем элементы вертикально по центру */
}}

/* Подсветка выбранного чатбокса */
.chatbox.active {
    background-color: auto;
}
.chatbox-content {
    max-width: 100%; /* Ограничьте максимальную ширину по содержимому */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Переносите длинные слова */
}

    </style>


    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="cover.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function updateMessages() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/update-messages', // Make sure this matches your mapping
                method: 'GET',
                cache: false, // Disable caching
                success: function(data) {
                    // Update the HTML content of the messages container
                    $('#incoming-messages').html(data);
                }
            });
        }

        // Update messages every 3 seconds
        setInterval(updateMessages, 3000);
    });


</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Функция для обновления выбранного чатбокса и сообщений
    function updateChatbox(username) {
        $('.chatbox').removeClass('active');
        $('.chatbox[data-username="' + username + '"]').addClass('active');

        // Получение сообщений для выбранного пользователя с помощью AJAX
        $.ajax({
            url: '/update-messages?username=' + username, // Обновите URL по необходимости
            method: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                // Обновление области отображения сообщений полученными данными
                $('#incoming-messages').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    // Обработка события нажатия на чатбокс
    $('.chatbox').click(function() {
        var selectedUsername = $(this).attr('data-username');
        updateChatbox(selectedUsername);
    });

    // Начальное обновление с первым пользователем
    if ($('.chatbox').length > 0) {
        var firstUsername = $('.chatbox:first').attr('data-username');
        updateChatbox(firstUsername);
    }

    // ... Остальной существующий код
});

</script>

<body class="d-flex h-100 text-center text-bg-dark">
<div class="chatbox-list-container">
    <ul class="chatbox-list">
        <li th:each="user : ${allUsers}" class="chatbox" th:data-username="${user.username}">
            <span th:text="${user.username}"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="d-none">
    <symbol id="check2" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M13.854 3.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-7 7a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3.5-3.5a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L6.5 10.293l6.646-6.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"/>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="circle-half" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 0 8 1v14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 1 8 0a8 8 0 0 1 0 16z"/>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="moon-stars-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M6 .278a.768.768 0 0 1 .08.858 7.208 7.208 0 0 0-.878 3.46c0 4.021 3.278 7.277 7.318 7.277.527 0 1.04-.055 1.533-.16a.787.787 0 0 1 .81.316.733.733 0 0 1-.031.893A8.349 8.349 0 0 1 8.344 16C3.734 16 0 12.286 0 7.71 0 4.266 2.114 1.312 5.124.06A.752.752 0 0 1 6 .278z"/>
        <path d="M10.794 3.148a.217.217 0 0 1 .412 0l.387 1.162c.173.518.579.924 1.097 1.097l1.162.387a.217.217 0 0 1 0 .412l-1.162.387a1.734 1.734 0 0 0-1.097 1.097l-.387 1.162a.217.217 0 0 1-.412 0l-.387-1.162A1.734 1.734 0 0 0 9.31 6.593l-1.162-.387a.217.217 0 0 1 0-.412l1.162-.387a1.734 1.734 0 0 0 1.097-1.097l.387-1.162zM13.863.099a.145.145 0 0 1 .274 0l.258.774c.115.346.386.617.732.732l.774.258a.145.145 0 0 1 0 .274l-.774.258a1.156 1.156 0 0 0-.732.732l-.258.774a.145.145 0 0 1-.274 0l-.258-.774a1.156 1.156 0 0 0-.732-.732l-.774-.258a.145.145 0 0 1 0-.274l.774-.258c.346-.115.617-.386.732-.732L13.863.1z"/>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="sun-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M8 12a4 4 0 1 0 0-8 4 4 0 0 0 0 8zM8 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-2A.5.5 0 0 1 8 0zm0 13a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-2A.5.5 0 0 1 8 13zm8-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5zM3 8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2A.5.5 0 0 1 3 8zm10.657-5.657a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707l-1.414 1.415a.5.5 0 1 1-.707-.708l1.414-1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0zm-9.193 9.193a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707L3.05 13.657a.5.5 0 0 1-.707-.707l1.414-1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0zm9.193 2.121a.5.5 0 0 1-.707 0l-1.414-1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 .707-.707l1.414 1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707zM4.464 4.465a.5.5 0 0 1-.707 0L2.343 3.05a.5.5 0 1 1 .707-.707l1.414 1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708z"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>

<div class="dropdown position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 mb-3 me-3 bd-mode-toggle">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end shadow" aria-labelledby="bd-theme-text">
        <li>
            <button type="button" class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" data-bs-theme-value="light" aria-pressed="false">
                <svg class="bi me-2 opacity-50 theme-icon" width="1em" height="1em"><use href="#sun-fill"></use></svg>
                Light
                <svg class="bi ms-auto d-none" width="1em" height="1em"><use href="#check2"></use></svg>
            </button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="button" class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" data-bs-theme-value="dark" aria-pressed="false">
                <svg class="bi me-2 opacity-50 theme-icon" width="1em" height="1em"><use href="#moon-stars-fill"></use></svg>
                Dark
                <svg class="bi ms-auto d-none" width="1em" height="1em"><use href="#check2"></use></svg>
            </button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="button" class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center active" data-bs-theme-value="auto" aria-pressed="true">
                <svg class="bi me-2 opacity-50 theme-icon" width="1em" height="1em"><use href="#circle-half"></use></svg>
                Auto
                <svg class="bi ms-auto d-none" width="1em" height="1em"><use href="#check2"></use></svg>
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="cover-container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
    <header class="mb-auto">
    </header>

    <main class="px-3">
        <!-- Вывод списка пользователей для отправки сообщений -->
        <form th:action="@{/send}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="senderUsername" th:value="${senderUsername}" />
            <label for="recipientUsername">Recipient:</label>
            <select name="recipientUsername">
                <option th:each="user : ${allUsers}" th:value="${user.username}" th:text="${user.username}"></option>
            </select>

            <br>
            <label for="messageText">Message:</label>
            <input type="text" name="messageText" required />
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
        <div class="message-list-container chatbox-content">
            <ul id="incoming-messages" th:fragment="messages" class="message-list">
                <li th:each="message : ${incomingMessages}">
                    <span th:text="${message.sender.username}"></span>:
                    <span th:text="${message.messageText}"></span> -
                    <span th:text="${#temporals.format(message.timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')}"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>


    </main>

    <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger position-absolute bottom-0 end-0 m-3">Logout</button>
    </form>

    <footer class="mt-auto text-white-50">
        <p>dev.by.Flaim92</p>
    </footer>
</div>
<script src="/docs/5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).